# Is there a name for name.d/ (e.g. /etc/httpd/conf.d) directories?

Tags: linux, include

I'm writing an application which reads a bunch of config files from a /etc/myapp.d folder (so /etc/myappd.d/*.conf). However, I don't understand the significance of the .d part.

Does this type of directory usage have a specific name, or is .d==directory and that's the end of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.d stands for 'directory'. It's a convention on linux: /etc/rcN.d, /etc/xinetd.d, etc. Generally, any directory named with .d will contain a set of files that some program will enumerate, read, and process.